# What does ～たまえ mean exactly and how do you use it?

Tags: meaning, verbs, subsidiary-verbs

I've seen the verb 給え【たまえ】, usually written in hiragana and after the stem of another verb, ending a phrase. I'm not too sure about its meaning.

I've read that it means "...please" but is that the only meaning? Also is it used in conversation and if so when/how should I use it?

Comment: Something like 読んでくれ給え ?  I've always known it as "please", but talking down a level or two.  In pop culture you'd here it being said to someone's subordinates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not-so-young native speaker here.  I personally have *never* used 「verb + たまえ」 myself or had another person say something to me using that structure.

The only places that I have actually heard it used have been:

1. **Fiction** (films, dramas, plays, novels, etc.) and
2. **Religious sermons**

In fiction, **adult male speakers** sometimes use 「verb + たまえ」 as a ***somewhat friendly imperative*** with younger colleagues.  In real life, however, I have *never* met such a male boss or co-worker in the companies I have worked for.

In religious sermons and prayers, 「verb + たまえ」 is quite often used when asking for blessings from above.

Comment: It's the imperative of the now-very-archaic verb 給ふ 'bestow'. Historically it was used a lot like 下さい is now, but it's very much fallen out of use except for for dramatic effect.